# Компиляция игры под Android на Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

Здраствуйте высоко уважаемые профессионалы. Я делаю игру под андройд в школу ко дню родного языка. Игра по типу викторины. Когда я начал компилировать игру начали появляться вот такие ошибки.
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
Build file 'C:\Users\123\Desktop\тест родного языка\Temp\gradleOut\launcher\build.gradle' line: 3

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':launcher'.

> Failed to apply plugin [id 'com.android.application']
> Your project path contains non-ASCII characters. This will most likely cause the build to fail on Windows. Please move your project to a different directory. See http://b.android.com/95744 for details. This warning can be disabled by adding the line 'android.overridePathCheck=true' to gradle.properties file in the project directory.

Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8

CommandInvokationFailure: Gradle build failed.
C:/Program Files/Unity/Hub/Editor/2019.4.13f1/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer\OpenJDK\bin\java.exe -classpath "C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.4.13f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\Tools\gradle\lib\gradle-launcher-5.1.1.jar" org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain "-Dorg.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4096m" "assembleRelease"

Build completed with a result of 'Failed' in 96 seconds (95686 ms)

UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+BuildMethodException: 20 errors

Вот основные скрипты:

Этот код отвечает за то какой сейчас вопрос, какие варианты ответов и какой ответ правильный

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Taks : MonoBehaviour
{
    public TextAsset All;
    string Text;
    public string TasK;
    public string Answers;
    public Text Tesk;
    public Text a1;
    public Text a2;
    public Text a3;
    public Text a4;
    public string True;

    void Start()
    {
        Text = All.text;
        string[] s = Text.Split('/');
        TasK = s[0];
        Answers = s[1];
        True = s[2];
        Tesk.text = TasK;
        string[] A = Answers.Split(';');
        a1.text = A[0];
        a2.text = A[1];
        a3.text = A[2];
        a4.text = A[3];
    }


    void Update()
    {
        
    }
}
```

Этот код отвечает за то чтобы при нажатии на неё определить правильный вариант ответа или нет

```
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using UnityEngine;
    using UnityEngine.UI;
    
    public class BTN_TXT : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public GameObject VPR;
        public Color gr;
        public Color fl;
        public Image th;
        public Text t;
        public Taks task;
        public TRUE tru;
        
    
    
        void Start()
        {
            
        }
    
        public void check()
        {
    
            if (t.text == task.True)
            {
    
                th.color = gr;
                StartCoroutine(Wait());
                tru.Score = tru.Score + 1;
            }
    
            else
            { 
                th.color = fl;
                StartCoroutine(Wait());
    
            }
        }
    
        IEnumerator Wait()
        {
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
            VPR.active = false;
        }
    
    }


А этот код отвечает за то чтобы вопросы были в рандомном порядке

public class LIST : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int I;
    public GameObject[] tasks;
    public int T = 0;
    public GameObject FIN;
    void Start()
    {
        tasks = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("TASK");
        I = Random.Range(0, tasks.Length);
        tasks[I].transform.GetChild(0).gameObject.active = true;
        FIN.active = false;

    }


    public void Randowm()
    {
        StartCoroutine(N());
        StartCoroutine(R());
    }
    IEnumerator N()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
        tasks = null;
        tasks = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("TASK");
        I = Random.Range(0, tasks.Length);
        tasks[I].transform.GetChild(0).gameObject.active = true;

    }
    IEnumerator R()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
        if (tasks.Length == 1)
        {
            tasks[I].transform.GetChild(0).gameObject.active = false;
            FIN.active = true;
        }
    }

    }
```

Я ещё только начинающий.
Помогите пожaлуйста.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

В пути к проекту не должно быть русских символов

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception. Build file 'C:\Users\123\Desktop\**тест родного языка**\Temp\gradleOut\launcher\build.gradle

Comment: Даже если это название игры?

Comment: @МаксимилианАляшев, да